# For every set there is a wellorder that cannot be injected in X (without using Replacement)

Tags: set-theory

Hartogs' Theorem states: If $X$ is a set, then there is an ordinal $\alpha$ such that there is no injection from $\alpha$ to $X$. The proof I am familiar with uses unique representation of wellorders by ordinals, which in turn requires the Axiom Scheme of Replacement. How do you prove the following **without** using Replacement or the Axiom of Choice?

> *For every set there is a wellorder such that there is no injection from the wellorder to the set.*

I had the idea to separate from $\{X\}\times \mathcal P(X \times X)$ the set of all wellorders on $X$ and then to extend this wellorder, but as far as I understand, without the Axiom of Choice we do not know whether there even exists a wellorder on $X$.

Comment: You prove it *the same way*. Just instead of using ordinals, you're using equivalence classes of well-orders of subsets of $X$.

Comment: Thank you very much!